# What is this line of code asking?

Tags: c#, null

```
    public Schedule Schedule
    {
        get
        {
            return (ContractConsignee == null ? null : ContractConsignee.Schedule);
        }
        set
        {
            if (ContractConsignee == null)
            {
                ContractConsignee = new ContractConsignee(Session);
                ContractConsignee.Assignments.Add(this);
            }
            ContractConsignee.Schedule = value;
        }
    }
```

Someone else wrote this code. I am trying to solve a bug in our system. I'm not familiar with:

```
 == null ? null : ContractConsignee.Schedule
```

Comment: This is a ternary operator:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: Microsoft provides search engine too in addition to C# and MSDN - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20what%20is%20question%20mark

Comment: @Rahul how `return ContractConsignee.Schedule` is equivalent to `return return ContractConsignee == null ? null : ContractConsignee.Schedule` ?

Answer (score 5):

`? :` is the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

If `ContractConsignee` is `null`, the getter returns `null`; otherwise, it will return `ContractConsignee.Schedule`.

Answer (score 2):

```
return (ContractConsignee == null ? null : ContractConsignee.Schedule);
```

is equivalent to / short form of

```
if (ContractConsignee == null)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return ContractConsignee.Schedule;
}
```